# Trying to give multiple IP's in jdbc ignite thin client

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I have two node ignite cluster, while running my java process in my dropwizard config file i am giving url as

`"url: "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.107,10.0.0.51"`, but it is giving error as `java.net.UnknownHostException: 10.0.0.107,10.0.0.51`.

I tried by adding url as

`url: "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.107,10.0.0.51"`

`url: "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.107:10800, 10.0.0.51:10800"`

`url: "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.107:10800 : 10.0.0.51:10800"`

`url: "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.107:10800 : jdbc:ignite:thin://10.0.0.51:10800"`

My Java process is not able to connect to ignite . Can someone help me?

Comment: I think u need to edit and format it for people to understand it easily

Comment: What version of Ignite are you using? It's clearly not parsing the comma-delimited list. This code was added last year, so it's certainly in 2.7 and possibly in 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you refer to https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-multiple-endpoints, but this document describes the latest version. I've double-checked `Ignite` source code and the outcome is that `Ignite` of version older that 2.5.0 doesn't support this `multiple-endpoint` feature. It would be great if you check your version.

Comment: Thanks, by changing the ignite version it started picking up